# API / Library to Integrate Forum within native Mobile Application

Tags: ios, integration, android-library, forum, ios-library

Want to implement Forum with below features:

Search
- User will be able to search for different topics within the forum

Quick Access (Recent Visits)
- Checkout topic/forum recent visits

Directory
- List of all the Topics

Read Later
- All messages added to the read later

One on on message
- Able to post message to a particular member who has posted the comment on the topic

Create new topic

- Ability for users to create topic and ask questions which will be monitored by admin and can delete any irrelevant messages

Can anyone guide me with any API or forum for the same?

Thanks

Comment: Hi.  Unfortunately asking for recommendations for off-site resources is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have been looking for APIs from forums such as TapaTalk, Topic'IT but did not get anything which will help me to initite the implementation but could not find any. If any assistance or guidance that can be provided will be appreciated.